# IE Information Bar, download file...how do I code for this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a web page (asp.net) that compiles a package then redirects the user to the download file via javascript (window.location = ....).  This is accompanied by a hard link on the page in case the redirect doesn't work - emulating the download process on many popular sites.  When the IE information bar appears at the top due to restricted security settings, and a user clicks on it to download the file, it redirects the user to the page, not the download file, which refreshes the page and removes the hard link.

What is the information bar doing here?  Shouldn't it send the user to the location of the redirect?  Am I setting something wrong in the headers of the download response, or doing something else wrong to send the file in the first place?

C# Code:

```
m_context.Response.Buffer = false;
m_context.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
m_context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString());
m_context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}_{1}.zip", downloadPrefix, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm")));
//send the file
```

Comment: It's hard to help here without more code...the redirect JS, the page markup, and the rest of the code to publish the zip file would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When a user agrees to download a file using the IE Information Bar, IE reloads the current page, not the page the file the user is trying to download.  The difference is that, once the page is reloaded, IE will allow the download script to go through without prompting the user.  I'm not sure what the thinking is on this from a design standpoint, but that's how it seems work.